# How to do a simple calculation in Django RestFrameWork

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

**model.py**

```
class SaleE(models.Model):
  qty = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  rate = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  tax = models.CharField(max_length=250,null="True")
  slno= models.CharField(max_length=250)
  ptype =models.CharField(max_length=250)
  pdiscription = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  pname = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  amount = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

**Serializer.py**

```
class SaleESerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SaleE
        fields = ('id','slno','pname','ptype','pdiscription','qty','rate','tax','amount')
```

Here i want to do a simple calculation for an example 
if i give a amount 200 in addition result should be like 400 in backend itself it should calculate so how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed for it in multiple ways: by overriding `clean` method, writing signal or override in serializer

**Override model's clean method**

```
class SaleE(models.Model):
    ....
    your model fields
    ....

    def clean(self):
        # perform any calculation you want to perform at here..
        # self: model instance of your current record
        self.amount = self.amount * 2
```

in clean method you can evaluate or modify your instance before save.

**Writing signals**

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=SaleE) # pre_save is signal type which will called before save method
def create_firebase_account(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    sender: sender model from which you'll receive signal from
    instance: model instance(record) which is saved (it will be instance of sender model)
    """
    if created:  # use this condition if you want to alter amount only at creation time
        instance.amount = instance.amount * 2
```

If you wish to only modify field value before save only at API call and not from shell or any other view, you can override `perform_create` method in view or `create` method in serializers

When you write signals it will perform calculation whenever `save()` method is called for model instance, but if you override in serializer it will only be able to calculate when you try to update/create model instance via API only